# How exactly does binary code get converted into letters?

Tags: binary

Out of curiosity, how exactly does binary code get converted into letters? I know there are sites that automatically convert binary to words for you but I wanna understand the specific, intermediary steps that binary code goes through before being converted into letters.

Comment: What do you mean by binary code? You mean from an ASCII code to the corresponding letter?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Assuming that by "binary code" you mean just plain old data (sequences of bits, or bytes), and that by "letters" you mean characters, the answer is in two steps.  But first, some background.

- A character is just a named symbol, like "LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A" or "GREEK SMALL LETTER PI" or "BLACK CHESS KNIGHT".  Do not confuse a character (abstract symbol) with a *glyph* (a picture of a character).
- A *character set* is a particular set of characters, each of which is associated with a special number, called its codepoint.  To see the codepoint mappings in the Unicode character set, see http://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/UnicodeData.txt.

Okay now here are the two steps:

1. The data, if it is textual, must be accompanied somehow by a *character encoding*, something like UTF-8, Latin-1, US-ASCII, etc.  Each character encoding scheme specifies in great detail how  byte sequences are interpreted as codepoints (and conversely how codepoints are encoded as byte sequences).
2. Once the byte sequences are interpreted as codepoints, you have your characters, because each character has a specific codepoint.

A couple notes:

- In some encodings, certain byte sequences correspond to no codepoints at all, so you can have character decoding errors.
- In some character sets, there are codepoints that are unused, that is, they correspond to no character at all.

In other words, not every byte sequence means something as text.

Answer (score 33):

Here's a way to convert binary numbers to ASCII characters that is often simple enough to do in your head.

**1 - Convert every 4 binary digits into one hex digit.**

Here's a binary to hex conversion chart:

```
0001 = 1 
0010 = 2 
0011 = 3 
0100 = 4 
0101 = 5
0110 = 6
0111 = 7
1000 = 8

1001 = 9
1010 = a (the hex number a, not the letter a)
1011 = b
1100 = c
1101 = d
1110 = e
1111 = f
```

(The hexadecimal numbers a through f are the decimal numbers 10 through 15. That's what hexadecimal, or "base 16" is - instead of each digit being capable of representing 10 different numbers [0 - 9], like decimal or "base 10" does, each digit is instead capable of representing 16 different numbers [0 - f].)

Once you know that chart, converting any string of binary digits into a string of hex digits is simple.

For example,

```
01000100 = 0100 0100 = 44 hex
1010001001110011 = 1010 0010 0111 0011 = a273 hex
```

Simple enough, right? It is a simple matter to convert a binary number of any length into its hexadecimal equivalent.

(This works because hexadecimal is base 16 and binary is base 2 and 16 is the 4th power of 2, so it takes 4 binary digits to make 1 hex digit. 10, on the other hand, is not a power of 2, so we can't convert binary to decimal nearly as easily.)

**2 - Split the string of hex digits into pairs.**

When converting a number into ASCII, every 2 hex digits is a character. So break the hex string into sets of 2 digits.

You would split a hex number like 7340298b392 this into 6 pairs, like this:

```
7340298b392 = 07 34 02 98 b3 92
```

(Notice I prepended a 0, since I had an odd number of hex digits.)

That's 6 pairs of hex digits, so its going to be 6 letters. (Except I know right away that 98, b3 and 92 aren't letters. I'll explain why in a minute.)

**3 - Convert each pair of hex digits into a decimal number.**

Do this by multiplying the (decimal equivalent of the) left digit by 16, and adding the 2nd.

For example, b3 hex = 11*16 + 3, which is 110 + 66 + 3, which is 179.
(b hex is 11 decimal.)

**4 - Convert the decimal numbers into ASCII characters.**

Now, to get the ASCII letters for the decimal numbers, simply keep in mind that in ASCII, 65 is an uppercase 'A', and 97 is a lowercase 'a'.

So what letter is 68?

68 is the 4th letter of the alphabet in uppercase, right?
65 = A, 66 = B, 67 = C, 68 = D.

So 68 is 'D'.

You take the decimal number, subtract 64 for uppercase letters if the number is less than 97, or 96 for lowercase letters if the number is 97 or larger, and that's the number of the letter of the alphabet associated with that set of 2 hex digits.

---

Alternatively, if you're not afraid of a little bit of easy hex arithmetic, you can skip step 3, and just go straight from hex to ASCII, by remembering, for example, that

```
hex 41 = 'A' 
hex 61 = 'a'
```

So subtract 40 hex for uppercase letters or 60 hex for lowercase letters, and convert what's left to decimal to get the alphabet letter number.

For example

```
01101100 = 6c, 6c - 60 = c = 12 decimal = 'l'
01010010 = 52, 52 - 40 = 12 hex = 18 decimal = 'R'
```

(When doing this, it's helpful to remember that 'm' (or 'M') is the 13 letter of the alphabet. So you can count up or down from 13 to find a letter that's nearer to the middle than to either end.)

I saw this on a shirt once, and was able to read it in my head:

```
01000100
01000001
01000100
```

I did it like this:

```
01000100 = 0100 0100 = 44 hex, - 40 hex = ucase letter 4 = D
01000001 = 0100 0001 = 41 hex, - 40 hex = ucase letter 1 = A
01000100 = 0100 0100 = 44 hex, - 40 hex = ucase letter 4 = D
```

The shirt said "DAD", which I thought was kinda cool, since it was being purchased by a pregnant woman. Her husband must be a geek like me.

---

How did I know right away that 92, b3, and 98 were not letters?

Because the ASCII code for a lowercase 'z' is 96 + 26 = 122, which in hex is 7a. 7a is the largest hex number for a letter. Anything larger than 7a is not a letter.

---

So that's how you can do it as a human.

How do computer programs do it?

For each set of 8 binary digits, convert it to a number, and look it up in an ASCII table.

(That's one pretty obvious and straight forward way. A typical programmer could probably think of 10 or 15 other ways in the space of a few minutes. The details depend on the computer language environment.)

Comment: thanks. I find it easier to read without the hex digits, aka see the byte `01000100` as `2^6+2^2`=68 directly.

Comment: Interesting. Let's see, I guess the right-most digit is 2^0, so 2^6 is the 7th digit from the right-most. 2^6 is.. 2,4,8,16,32,64.. and 2^2 is 2*2 which is 4, so, right, that'd be 68. Ascii codes are 8 bits wide, so I guess if you know the powers of 2 out to 7 bits (since 01111010 is the biggest letter), that method could be practical enough, although something like 01011010 might take longer that way than if you just know the hex digits out to 4 bits; 0101 = 5, 1010 = A, so 5A. Converting to a letter: 0x5A - 0x40 (cap letters) = 0x1A = 16 + 10 = 26 (in cap letters) = 'Z'.

Comment: If you really prefer to work in decimal, I guess actually you can just know the decimal values out to 4 bits, and for each set of 8 bits, multiply the left set by 16 and add the 2nd set. So 0101:1010 = 5:10 = 5 * 16 + 10 = 50 + 30 + 10 = 90. If you know 64 is the decimal number to subtract for capital letters, you get 26 ('Z') that way.

Answer (score 10):

Do you mean the conversion `011001100110111101101111` → `foo`, for example? You just take the binary stream, split it into separate bytes (`01100110`, `01101111`, `01101111`) and look up the [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) character that corresponds to given number. For example, `01100110` is 102 in decimal and the ASCII character with code 102 is `f`:

```
$ perl -E 'say 0b01100110'
102
$ perl -E 'say chr(102)'
f
```

([See what the `chr` function does](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chr.html).) You can generalize this algorithm and have a different number of bits per character and different encodings, the point remains the same.

Comment: Just incase anyone else didn't know:

`-e` commandline
may be used to enter one line of program. If -e is given, Perl will not look for a filename in the argument list. Multiple -e commands may be given to build up a multi-line script. Make sure to use semicolons where you would in a normal program.

`-E` commandline
behaves just like -e, except that it implicitly enables all optional features (in the main compilation unit). See feature.

https://perldoc.pl/perlrun#-e-commandline

Answer (score 3):

To read binary ASCII characters with great speed using only your head:

Letters start with leading bits 01. Bit 3 is on (1) for lower case, off (0) for capitals. Scan the following bits 4–8 for the first that is on, and select the starting letter from the same index in this string: “PHDBA” (think P.H.D., Bachelors in Arts). E.g. 1xxxx = P, 01xxx = H, etc. Then convert the remaining bits to an integer value (e.g. 010 = 2), and count that many letters up from your starting letter. E.g. 01001010 => H+2 = J.

Comment: Wow, this is super cool! Some actual kinda smart person came up with this. I bet this has spread by word of mouth through the high schools and colleges and now I'm the last to hear about it by years, lol. It could maybe a little more thoroughly layed out and explained, here, but. I think it's a little bit better method than the one I proposed, maybe.

Comment: If you missed out on this in college, so did I. I just noticed the pattern when trying to decode a T-shirt with a lot of binary on it. BTW, thanks for explaining the binary parts in your answer. I just assume some knowledge because it’s all over this page. :-)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.roubaixinteractive.com/PlayGround/Binary_Conversion/The_Characters.asp it just looks here... (not HERE but it has a table).

There are 8 bits in a byte. One byte can be one symbol. One bit is either on or off.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do this take 010010001001001 split it into two bits 8 letter each (01001000, 01001001). Then issue the powers

01001000.       01001001.

The first 8 ignore the first three they determine if it's capital or not, the go right to left doing powers of 2 (2^1, 2^2 2^3 2^4 2^5). So then add all the ones up , there's only one, and it = 8, and te eight letter in the alphabet is h so our first bit is the letter h, try it on the other bit