# LDRB r3, [r0] not loading the first byte into r3

Tags: assembly, arm

r0 = 0x00000090 
string in r0 in Memory view shows - `and the man said they must go`
LDRB r3, [r0] 
After this if i check r3 = 0x00000061 
in Memory it shows `Q...S`
I am using Keil to run this ARM7 big endian assembly.
LDRB is supposed to load 1 byte into r3 but it doesnt seem to be doing so.
r3 memory view should have been `a..` as it would have loaded the first byte from the string `and the man...`
Either I am looking at the wrong place or sometimes I have noticed that Keil doesnt work properly.

Comment: `61` is ASCII `'a'` so it does appear to work correctly.

Comment: [How exactly does binary code get converted into letters?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32150907) appears to be a good duplicate for the fact that `0x61` *is* `'a'`

Comment: I am little bit confused here r3 = 0x00000061 is the address in register r3. So the address 0x00000061 if i look at the memory at this address that shows Q...S
Is it that when i hover over r3 its showing me the contents of r3 only. I think i got it. I got confused. So r1, r2, r3,  all these registers are fixed when i hover over it it shows me the value of r3

Comment: arm uses two different big endian schemes be32 and be8, the armv4t used in the arm7 is be32 and armv6 and armv7 use be8.  you want to do say ldr r2,[r0] and your ldrb r3,[r0].  you should see 0x61XXXXXX if an arm7, 0xXXXXXX61 if an armv7.  Even better write 0x11223344 to r0 first using str then do the reads.